# How to import an HEIC image?

Tags: import, image, format

As of iOS 11, iPhones save images with a new compression format [HEIC](https://www.cultofmac.com/487808/heif-vs-jpeg-image-files/). Now all my photos are all in this format and I'd like to import them to Mathematica but this is not a supported image filetype.

Are there any third party packages available for this?

Comment: Workaround: Save the pics to a folder, then they are converted to JPG. Import from this folder

Comment: Maybe it's worth to have a look at GPAC (https://gpac.wp.imt.fr). It's a package of command line tools capable of conversion from and to HEIC. I haven't tried it, though.

Comment: @mgamer I like the compression of HEIC (better than jpeg).

Comment: https://imazing.com/guides/how-to-convert-heic-to-jpeg

Comment: There are different types of 3-rd party software can help you view and open this kind of new format files. Fact is that both heic viewer and heic converter can do that well. See this review to know what they are: [heic viewer](https://www.joyoshare.com/reviews/heic-viewer.html)

Comment: @Yiliayoung I think the desire was for a way to do it directly in Mathematica (although probably making use of a third-party library)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upgrade to Mathematica version 12.1.
https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/HEIF.html